# Loop through order collection and send email invoice

Tags: magento2, sales-order, invoice, order-email

I try to loop through my order collection to make invoice order and send invoice email programmatically,all the invoice were created successfully, but only the invoice email from last order in loop that i receive.

```
foreach ($orders as $order){
    if ($order->canInvoice()) { 
        $invoice = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService')->prepareInvoice($order);
        $invoice->register();
        $invoice->save();
        $invoice->pay();
        $transactionSave = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction')
            ->addObject($invoice)
            ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
        $transactionSave->save();
        $this->invoiceSender->send($invoice,true);
    }
}
```